# Empty GeoServer Layer

Tags: geoserver, kml

I am able to create a published layers and layer groups in GeoServer based on a SQL Server store.

When I try to preview the layer in any method (e.g. OpenLayers or KML) it comes up empty. The bounds are correct (i.e. Google Earth spins to the correct location) but the geometry is not displaying in the map.

I suspect this is to do with a configuration setting for my new layer in GeoServer but I am stumped about what it might be.

Here is the layer that I am trying to get to work:

http://185.38.105.91:8080/geoserver/SCXBC/wms/kml?layers=SCXBC:uk_parliament_initial_review

Here is an example of a sample layer on the same server which does work:

http://185.38.105.91:8080/geoserver/topp/wms/kml?layers=topp:tasmania_state_boundaries

Here is a composite screenshot of the layer settings:

[image]

Comment: Do you check the style? The GetFeatureInfo on OpenLayers Preview works?

Comment: please show us how you configured the view

Comment: @OscarCampo I set the style to the same "green" one that works on the Tasmanian example.

Comment: @OscarCampo I have tried a GetFeatureInfo request which you can see at http://185.38.105.91:8080/geoserver/SCXBC/wms?request=GetFeatureInfo&service=WMS&version=1.1.0&layers=SCXBC:uk_parliament_initial_review&styles=&bbox=-84702.61914736108,-9272.577651805477,676223.7241900009,1242876.667023777&width=466&height=768&srs=EPSG:27700&x=353&y=145&format=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml

Comment: @IanTurton no problem I have created a composite image of the layer settings so you can see them. If this is not what you meant by view please let me know and I will show you what you want (e.g. by view I often think database).

Comment: The server you're pointing to does not seem to be reachable

Comment: @AndreaAime are you able to give a little more information about that please. It works with the Tasmanian layers so I am not sure why the server would be reachable for those but not available for the problem layer.

Comment: Are you sure the ogr_geometry column is a polygon? I don't see anything obvious on the geoserver setup, but the fact that the bounds are set correctly makes me think the geometry is there but is being ignored by the style because it isn't a polygon.

Comment: @Evan thanks for that. I am fairly sure it is a polygon because when I imported the shapefile into MS SQL Server it imported the ogr_geometry as a 2 coord_dimension with geometry type POLYGON. An example would be POLYGON ((327176.71910405532 672489.81075723656, 327270.50991264172 672450.85149827786, 327285.66073556896 672440.75094966777, 327071.38481133431 672586.48743685335, 327107.45819925051 672540.31350032054, 327176.71910405532 672489.81075723656))

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the type of layer? It has a different icon beside it (i.e. not a polygon, line or point icon). I do not know what the icon symbolises. Here is the icon http://185.38.105.91:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/resource/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerBasePage/img/icons/geosilk/vector-ver-7D907ECB447ED3214265284C9C1061A4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that provided suggestions to the problem, it was helpful in me finding the solution.

I managed to narrow it down to what seems to be corrupt and empty data in the ogr_geometry column. As an example I made a view for the city of Edinburgh which has pure data and it works without any problem:

http://185.38.105.91:8080/geoserver/SCXBC/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=SCXBC:view1stEdinburghAll&styles=&bbox=314999.51760000177,664644.7966612317,336745.01917041466,678826.1972775348&width=768&height=500&srs=EPSG:27700&format=application/openlayers